# how can i make sure that my node js json doesn't send an 'undefined' when called by an http javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Ok, currently i've been having this problem. I'm trying to send a json file from my node server to my html javascript but its been getting an undefined. Here is the sample code:

server side:

```js
app.get("/resources",(req, resp)=>{
 resp.json({stuff:"goodbye"})
})
```

html javascript:

```js
var slink = "http://localhost:3000/resources"
fetch(slink).then((resp)=>{
 console.log(resp)
 return resp.json;
}).then((json)=>{
 console.log(json.data)
})
```

All of it runs but when console.log(json.data) runs, it returns an undefined. Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: `resp.json` is a function.

Comment: Is there a `data` property on the JSON object you're sending? Have you tried logging just `json`?

Comment: what Roland Starke said; should be `resp.json()` instead of `resp.json`

Comment: for logging just json, it outputs ƒ json() { [native code] }

Comment: it works, just using resp.json()